# Vagrant fails to authenticate

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

In my vagrant file I have the following

```
config.vm.define "core-supervisor" do |cs|
  cs.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-6.5-64-puppet"
  cs.vm.network "public_network", :adapter=>2 , type: "dhcp"
  cs.vm.hostname = "supervisor.dev.domain.com"

  cs.ssh.username = "me"
  cs.ssh.private_key_path = "/home/me/.ssh/my_key"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
```

When I attempt to login I see

```
core-supervisor: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
core-supervisor: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
core-supervisor: SSH username: me
core-supervisor: SSH auth method: private key
core-supervisor: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
core-supervisor: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
core-supervisor: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
core-supervisor: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
core-supervisor: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

When I run

```
 virtualbox  vagrant ssh-config core-supervisor
```

I get

```
  Host core-supervisor
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User me
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/me/.vagrant/machines/core-supervisor/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

I feel that the identity file is incorrect?

My key is added to the ssh-agent, so I don't think that is a problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you remove the parts to set personal username and ssh key and try again? Normally Vagrant use the default account `vagrant`, and you can login with command `vagrant ssh` directly.

Comment: My box is configured for the user shown. I can login with this user from the command line.